# Why does java.sql.Statement break backward compatibility?

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

There are three more methods declared in `Statement` interface since version 1.6.

As I understand, this breaks one of the biggest java advantages - backward compatibility. My project just not compiled any more after transition from jdk 1.5 to jdk 1.6 and I have to change the code.

What is the reasoning of adding these three methods (`isPoolable`, `setPoolable`, `isClosed`) in such a bad way?

Comment: Methods have been added to the JDBC API every major java version since 1.1 - this is nothing new.

Comment: As a user you should not be impacted, only if you use a JDBC driver which does not implement JDBC 4. If you develop your own JDBC driver, then you should know this is expected: there have been 5+ versions of JDBC, each adding new methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added interface methods are a problem if you implement the interface e.g. you are writing your own JDBC driver.  If you have a library which uses these method calling a library which doesn't implement these methods you will get a NoSuchMethodError.

I assume these methods were added because for most use cases its considered harmless.